Why is Hyperledger Besu receipt returning in 10 seconds fixed intervals?
We have Hyperledger network hosted on 5 nodes and published some smart contracts on that network. Then we have built an .NET web api which interacts with network through Nethereum library.
The issue is when calling the web3.TransactionManager.SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync method network always respond in 10 seconds interval. To make it more clear the timestamp is always hh:mm:01, and hh:mm:11 and so on when we get receipt from Besu network. Protocol is QBFT with block period second set to 2, request timeout seconds set to 5, and no gas price.
The effect of this is that every transaction will be confirmed to be successful between 0-10 seconds depending on how far request is to next hh:mm:x1 mark. Any ideas?
Hyperledger Besu version: 24.3.3
In following image you can see logs with 2 attempts and both return receipts at hh:mm:x1 timestamps.
Top 2 tries are with SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync method.
Bottom try is sending SendTransactionAsync method first and then polling method GetTransactionReceipt.SendRequestAsync every 0.5 second with Polly.

